# Make Text Input Box Transparent? Should be simple?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to make my form input transparent and over lay it on top of my div.  Basically I want the text field to be transparent to whatever is behind it.  Any suggestions?

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
  .WRAPPER {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 575px;
    width: 975px;
    background-image: url(exit-gate/exit-gate-bg.png);
    top: auto;
    margin: -8px;
  }

  body {
    background-color: #000;
  } 
</style>

<style type="text/css">
  term {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
</style>

</head>



<body>
  <div id="WRAPPER"> 
    <div class="term"><input name="email" type="text" id="email">
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="insert_ac.php">
        <input type="image" src="exit-gate/white-box-10.png" alt="{alternate text}" name="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: your "term" css declaration needs to be ".term" to have any hope of working. Your DOM structure is messed up as well, you certainly shouldn'y have a "div" after your closing HTML tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
#email {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color:white;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    height:30px;
    transition:height 1s;
    -webkit-transition:height 1s;
}
#email:focus {
    height:50px;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pWnhN/2)

Comment: I would go with `transparent` over an `rgba` value.  As older browsers will default to the solid color.  In this case, black.

Comment: @Hiral, thank you that worked!

One more question... How would you suggest I specify the font, size, and color of the text when the visitor types, and also, specify the size of the text box?  

Thank you!!!

Comment: @user3089680 I have edited answer. [did you mean like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/pWnhN/2/)

Answer (score 5):

this looks ways too simple but it worked for me:

```
 <input type="text" id="SI"/>
```

this is my input field, I gave it an ID(SI), then in my CSS:

```
#SI{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

added the transparency to the element with SI id; the background became visible.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting, on macOS and iOS, in any browser, the "user agent stylesheet" will override textbox style. You can override this (including the ::focus glow) by adding !important.

```css
#mybox {
    background-color: transparent!important;
    border-color: transparent!important;
    outline: transparent!important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mybox" value="Textbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

saying I want a transparent color is like having the parent's color so put the value of `background-color` as `inherit`.

for me this helped:

```
<input type="text" />
```

style:

```
input {
    background-color:inherit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style type="text/css">
 input {
  background-color : white;
  border-color: transparent;

 }
</style>
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```